# How would I get taint to spread?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-thaumcraft

I was wondering how I would get taint to spread. My friend has been gone for a while and I want to prank him by tainting his base. I discovered that if you throw bottled taint in an eerie biome, then it makes spreadable taint. The taint was spreading good for a while until it stopped. I kept polluting the area with crucibles and I placed a sinister node there to see if that would help. I think the node killed it more. How would I get it to start spreading again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tainted Creepers and Tainted Sheep can produce Taint. Flowing Flux Goo can also be used to spread taint.